# Iphone:removing the toolbar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitoolbar

I am developing an Iphone application.
I have a Controller say "StepMopdeView".I have displayed a toolbar on this screen
using statement [self.parentViewController.view addSubview:navigateToolBar];

I want the toolbar to be displayed on this this screen but it is displayed on all the screens.
I dont want this toolbar to be displayed on any other screens.I am trying to do this but not able to achieve it.Can any one please guide me regarding how can i do it?

Thanks,
Yogesh Chaudhari

Answer (score 1):

simply call `[navigateToolBar setHidden: YES];` in the `viewWillDisappear:` method of the the viewController that created the toolbar.

Comment: Hi WrightsCS.I have tried to hide the toolbar it doesnt work.Just now after doing lot of R&D i have done it with following code:                [[self.parentViewController.view.subviews objectAtIndex:2] removeFromSuperview]; in ViewWillAppear and [self.navigateToolBar removeFromSuperview]; in ViewDidDsiappear